# jupyter notebook crashed after traning a model

Tags: jupyter-notebook

I'm training a pytorch-based neural network model on jupyter notebook.

After 2 hours' training, I run the next cell, and the tab directly crashed,as shown in the figure.

[image]
And the terminal shows:`MemoryError [I 16:32:46.267 NotebookApp] KernelRestarter: restarting kernel (1/5), keep random ports WARNING:root:kernel b4d13532-a648-42bc-932e-cc5acf92abd0 restarted`

Why and how can I solve it?

Comment: You can visit [jupyter Notebook keeps crashing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50785665/kernel-keeps-dying-in-jupyter-notebook)

Comment: thanks! I have visited the link ,but my error is quite different from that , I met the error when I run one of the cell in my jupyter notebook,not when I start notebook.And I met memory error not kernel died