# After installing SciKeras the kernel dies when importing Tensorflow

Tags: python, tensorflow

I am migrating from tf.keras.wrappers.scikit_learn to Scikeras.
I have created a new fresh environment with python=3.7 (to be compatible with Tensorflow).
Then I issue the command:

```
'pip install scikeras[tensorflow]'      (ref. https://pypi.org/project/scikeras/)
```

but I get

```
'zsh: no matches found: scikeras[tensorflow]'
```

I therefore try with:

```
'pip install scikeras tensorflow'
```

which executes successfully.

When I execute

'import tensorflow'

in my notebook in an isolated cell, the kernel dies. (in another attempt I also tried
'pip install scikeras tensorflow==2.7 with the same result' ). I am using a M1 mac.

Has anyone managed to successfully install and use SciKeras?

Comment: have you tried running `pip install scikerastensorflow` without square brackets?

Comment: Yes, as mentioned in my post. Same result...

Comment: Does this answer your question? [kernel keeps dying in jupyter notebook](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50785665/kernel-keeps-dying-in-jupyter-notebook)

Comment: Not really because my issue was linked to tensorflow not working on M1 Mac

Answer (score 2):

try with `pip install scikeras`

it has worked for me.

Comment: Mind you, I am/was using a M1 mac. When I logged the incident 'pip install scikeras' was not working. Overtime, after a couple of new versions of tensorflow-mac, it started working.

Answer (score 1):

Check this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/59259547/8691571
Excerpt:

> Try running the code that is causing the kernel to die in a terminal or in ipython... common issue I have identified is the use of SSE4.1 in later versions of tensorflow...  If this is the case, uninstall tensorflow and install with conda: conda install tensorflow==1.12.0, for instance.